# Unable to deposit into AAVEv3 via web3

Tags: web3js, javascript, polygon, defi, aave

I'm attempting to deposit WMATIC on the Polygon chain into AAVEv3, but I'm getting a revert.

I'm running a forked version of Polygon mainnet locally with ganache. I'm using the first account provided by ganache to do my testing.

Here's my script:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');
const fs = require('fs');

const web3 = new Web3(new Web3.providers.WebsocketProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545'));
const POOL_ABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('aavev3/abi/IPool.json'))['abi'];
const PAP_ABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('aavev3/abi/IPoolAddressesProvider.json'))['abi'];
const WIERC20_ABI = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync('aavev3/abi/WIERC20.json'));
const WMATIC_ADDR = "0x0d500B1d8E8eF31E21C99d1Db9A6444d3ADf1270";
const WETH_ADDR = "0x7ceb23fd6bc0add59e62ac25578270cff1b9f619";
const  PAP_ADDR = "0xa97684ead0e402dC232d5A977953DF7ECBaB3CDb";

let wmatic_deposit_amount = "800";
let weth_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(WIERC20_ABI, WETH_ADDR);
let wmatic_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(WIERC20_ABI, WMATIC_ADDR);
let pap_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(PAP_ABI, PAP_ADDR);

(async() => {
    const deposit_in_wei = web3.utils.toWei(wmatic_deposit_amount);
    // Use first account provided by ganache. Should be unlocked.
    const user = (await web3.eth.getAccounts())[0];

    // Get pool address from pool address provider contract (recommended by aave)
    const POOL_ADDR = await pap_contract.methods.getPool().call();
    let pool_contract = new web3.eth.Contract(POOL_ABI, POOL_ADDR);

    let init_wmatic_balance = web3.utils.fromWei(await wmatic_contract.methods.balanceOf(user).call());

    // Quick hack to check if I need to give the account WMATIC
    if (init_wmatic_balance < 1) {

        await wmatic_contract.methods.deposit().send({from: user, value: deposit_in_wei}); 

    }

    await wmatic_contract.methods.approve(POOL_ADDR, deposit_in_wei).send({from: user});

    await pool_contract.methods.supply(WMATIC_ADDR, deposit_in_wei, user, 0).send({from: user});
})();
```

ABIs were taken from the aave repository.

Everything works fine, except the supply call. Here's the error I get:

```
Error: Transaction has been reverted by the EVM:
{
  "transactionHash": "0xe6d12b38de5370c1c568a2872b66d3384cde63e1fa6da9c5553e410e4f7b82bc",
  "transactionIndex": 0,
  "blockNumber": 28686538,
  "blockHash": "0xffb0d1762ac79e0b30f15a37080fa4cbe08f87b082e745df2d3bd6602ee9afc9",
  "from": "0xf39fd6e51aad88f6f4ce6ab8827279cfffb92266",
  "to": "0x794a61358d6845594f94dc1db02a252b5b4814ad",
  "cumulativeGasUsed": 88188,
  "gasUsed": 88188,
  "contractAddress": null,
  "logsBloom": "0x00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000",
  "status": false,
  "effectiveGasPrice": 2500000011,
  "type": "0x2",
  "events": {}
}
```

Package versions:

- node: 18.2.0
- web3: 1.7.3

What is the correct way of supplying assets to AAVEv3 via web3?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up switching from ganache to anvil and it fixed this particular issue. Not entirely sure why there's a discrepancy in execution.